# How to copy "LINK/URL" to clip board in android application programmatically?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Is there any way to copy a link into clipboard

I want to copy a link to clip board.
I have an application in which I am using YouTube player. I want to restrict user to copy link, so for that I thought of using clipboard i.e whenever something is copied from my activity, I override it with some other text, so that when user paste it the other text get displayed instead of YouTube video url.

This is working fine, but when I click in some text , I can see the copied link under link section of clipboard.

My goal is to override the video url with some other dummy url or to clear the url copied into clipboard.

This leads to a major bug in my app, so If anyone can help  then it would be great for me.

Comment: Please provide code also, so that we can assist in better way

Comment: Why you not disable copy only instead of changing text in clipboard?

Comment: @AkashKashyap Is there any way to disable copy option in YouTube player? We can do that in EditText,TextView and other views, but I was unable to do that in YouTube player

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the ClipboardManager to copy a link to the clipboard. Here's an example:

```
val clipboard = getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
val clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", "your_link_here")
clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip)
```

To clear the clipboard, you can simply call `clipboard.clearPrimaryClip()`.

Keep in mind that overriding the clipboard can be seen as a negative user experience and could lead to user frustration. It's generally better to allow users to copy links and provide other ways of protecting your content.

Comment: I am exactly using the same code, but the problem in that is if I add pate it directly somewhere I am getting the new copied text. but when I open whatsapp, and just put cursor there , at that time  if we expand the clipboard, then the new text which we override is displayed and under link section we copied url is also displayed.